# MySQL Asynchronous?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

Im basically facing a blocking problem.
I have my server coded based on C++ Boost.ASIO using 8 threads since the server has 8 logical cores.

My problem is a thread may face 0.2~1.5 seconds of blocking on a MySQL query and I honestly don't know how to go around that since MySQL C++ Connector does not support asynchronous queries, and I don't know how to design the server "correctly" to use multiple threads for doing the queries.

This is where I'm asking for opinions of what to do in this case.
Create 100 threads for async' query sql?
Could I have an opinion from experts about this?

Comment: How many concurrent SQL queries do you anticipate? How many queries/second do you need to support? Without requirements, I'd say: just queue the queries, and post back when done.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, the proper solution to this would be to extend Asio and write a `mysql_service` implementation to integrate this. I was almost going to [find out how this is done right away](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html#asio_extensions), but I wanted to get started using an "emulation".

The idea is to have

- your business processes using an `io_service` (as you are already doing)
- a database "facade" interface that dispatches async queries into a *different* queue (io_service) and posts the completion handler back onto the business_process `io_service`

*A subtle tweak needed here you need to keep the io_service on the business process side from shutting down as soon as it's job queue is empty, since it might still be awaiting a response from the database layer.*

So, modeling this into a quick demo:

```
namespace database
{
    // data types
    struct sql_statement { std::string dml; };
    struct sql_response { std::string echo_dml; }; // TODO cover response codes, resultset data etc.
```

I hope you will forgive my gross simplifications :/

```
struct service
{
    service(unsigned max_concurrent_requests = 10)
        : work(io_service::work(service_)),
        latency(mt19937(), uniform_int<int>(200, 1500)) // random 0.2 ~ 1.5s
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < max_concurrent_requests; ++i)
            svc_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &service_));
    }

    friend struct connection;

private:
    void async_query(io_service& external, sql_statement query, boost::function<void(sql_response response)> completion_handler)
    {
        service_.post(bind(&service::do_async_query, this, ref(external), std::move(query), completion_handler));
    }

    void do_async_query(io_service& external, sql_statement q, boost::function<void(sql_response response)> completion_handler)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(latency())); // simulate the latency of a db-roundtrip

        external.post(bind(completion_handler, sql_response { q.dml }));
    }

    io_service service_;
    thread_group svc_threads; // note the order of declaration
    optional<io_service::work> work;

    // for random delay
    random::variate_generator<mt19937, uniform_int<int> > latency;
};
```

The service is what coordinates a maximum number of concurrent requests (on the "database io_service" side) and ping/pongs the completion back onto another io_service (the async_query/do_async_query combo). This stub implementation emulates latencies of 0.2~1.5s in the obvious way :)

Now comes the client "facade"

```
struct connection
{
    connection(int connection_id, io_service& external, service& svc)
        : connection_id(connection_id),
          external_(external), 
          db_service_(svc)
    { }

    void async_query(sql_statement query, boost::function<void(sql_response response)> completion_handler)
    {
        db_service_.async_query(external_, std::move(query), completion_handler);
    }
  private:
    int connection_id;
    io_service& external_;
    service& db_service_;
};
```

`connection` is really only a convenience so we don't have to *explicitly* deal with various queues on the calling site.

Now, let's implement a demo business process in good old Asio style:

```
namespace domain
{
    struct business_process : id_generator
    {
        business_process(io_service& app_service, database::service& db_service_) 
            : id(generate_id()), phase(0), 
            in_progress(io_service::work(app_service)),
            db(id, app_service, db_service_)
        { 
            app_service.post([=] { start_select(); });
        }

    private:
        int id, phase;
        optional<io_service::work> in_progress;

        database::connection db;

        void start_select() {
            db.async_query({ "select * from tasks where completed = false" }, [=] (database::sql_response r) { handle_db_response(r); });
        }

        void handle_db_response(database::sql_response r) {
            if (phase++ < 4)
            {
                if ((id + phase) % 3 == 0) // vary the behaviour slightly
                {
                    db.async_query({ "insert into tasks (text, completed) values ('hello', false)" }, [=] (database::sql_response r) { handle_db_response(r); });
                } else
                {
                    db.async_query({ "update * tasks set text = 'update' where id = 123" }, [=] (database::sql_response r) { handle_db_response(r); });
                }
            } else
            {
                in_progress.reset();
                lock_guard<mutex> lk(console_mx);
                std::cout << "business_process " << id << " has completed its work\n";
            }
        }
    };

}
```

This business process starts by posting itself on the app service. It then does a number of db queries in succession, and eventually exits (by doing `in_progress.reset()` the app service is made aware of this).

A demonstration main, starting 10 business processes on a single thread:

```
int main()
{
    io_service app;
    database::service db;

    ptr_vector<domain::business_process> bps;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        bps.push_back(new domain::business_process(app, db));
    }

    app.run();
}
```

In my sample, business_processes don't do any CPU intensive work, so there's no use in scheduling them across CPU's, but if you wanted you could easily achieve this, by replacing the `app.run()` line with:

```
thread_group g;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
    g.create_thread(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &app));
g.join_all();
```

See the demo running **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be41991d783c0c10)**

Comment: As I said previously, I don't know a lot about asio (though I used to work with Chris Kohlhoff, who wrote it -- a very smart guy) so I cannot add much to your solution.  It appears that you are using asynch completion handlers so threads are not waiting on database completion.  I should probably have anticpated that, since the "a" in asio is for "asynch".  I'll blame old-age :-)

Comment: To clarify: I was expecting an asynchronous link for the COMMs between the client and the server, I didn't realise it was also asynch between the servers listener and the database.

Comment: The COMMs are pretty much out of our control, unless you consider rewriting the [connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/). Some libraries made this extensible. LibCurl is pretty cool in that respect (see [`CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL guru, but the following is generic multithreading advice.

- Having `NumberOfThreads == NumberOfCores` is appropriate when none of the threads ever block and you are just splitting the load over all CPUs.
- A common pattern is to have multiple threads per CPU, so one is executing while another is waiting on something.
- In your case, I'd be inclined to set `NumberOfThreads = n * NumberOfCores` where 'n' is read from a config file, a registry entry or some other user-settable value.  You can test the system with different values of 'n' to fund the optimum.  I'd suggest somewhere around 3 for a first guess.

Comment: It seems to me that you're just not very familiar with Boost Asio (or similar asynchronous IO libraries, like libuv). The best advice for IO-contended applications is usually to multiplex the IO on as few threads as possible - typically 1. Creating many threads to "compensate" for the blocking is really just piling on more bottle necks (threads consume resources and create a growing scheduling overhead)

Comment: @sehe - You are correct that I am not familiar with boost::asio, however I have worked with a number of multithreaded comms systems.  If asio/mysql has a thread pool and does proper job management, so that waiting jobs do not hog a thread, then extra threads are unhelpful.  If it lets threads sleep, waiting for i/o (as the question suggests) then extra threads to keep the CPU busy will generally improve performance.  Do you know how asio/mysql manages jobs?

Comment: asio/mysql doesn't manage jobs, that's the point. Asio services do not "hog" a thread while waiting, but Asio has not been told about the Mysql interface (yet). See my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I've just posted an answer based on my current understanding of Asio. I think there's a cleaner way by writing a proper extension service. That should not be much more complicated (it's doing the same thing), but it would integrate better (e.g. with [`strand`s](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) and [coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core.html)). It does show what Asio is capable of; note the fact that all business processes are on a single thread, yet freely multiplexed.